# Encrypting a string in PHP

Tags: php, variables, customization

Okay, so I've got a php script something like the following:

```
<?php
$name = "Steve Jobs";
header('Location: http://www.apple.com/custom.php&name=' . $name);
?>
```

Now, I happen to find it kind of embarrasing having the URL of this custom "Hi there, Steve Jobs" page have a URL of `http://www.apple.com/custom.php&name=Steve%20Jobs`, and would therefore like to encode it.

Is there an easy way to make this name be more obscure? Is there a way to avoid passing it in the URL altogether?

Comment: Umm that header does nothing....

Comment: Crap... Well, it works in my script, so just imagine that it works ^.^

Comment: Yup. To redirect using `header`, you need to do `header('Location: http://someaddress.com');`.

Comment: You could use $_POST if you are setting $name via a form

Comment: @Marc Towler, it's being sent from a PHP script.

Comment: @Marc It would still appear in the URL, though.

Comment: More to the point, what if `.../custom.php?name=I am a poopy head'` get submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid passing variables around in the URL you could use [session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) using the `$_SESSION` array.

You can check out the PHP docs for some [basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), as well as other examples.

Comment: Don't really want to go too advanced though...

Comment: This is not advanced PHP. Your current solution is arguably the simplest, anything else would be more complex. Even then, not more complex by much.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to base64_encode($name), then base64_decode on the other end.

Comment: I would say that many people will still recognise base64 encoding, it has a characteristic look about it and is easily decoded. If your aim is to hide data from the end user, this a bad way to go about doing it. If your aim is just to make a URL look more "technical"... then that's awful!

Comment: Alex, I agree, this is less than ideal. But if his only reason is that it looks tacky to have the text in the url, then this is the easiest way to have the fewest changes possible to the rest of the code and accomplish the goal. Someone who could decode it probably wouldn't care about the 'tackiness' of having the un-encoded variable in the url, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can store the name in cookie or session, read it on the next page, and remove it from session/cookie. In this way, it won't be included in the URL anyway

If you just do not want to pass it as a plain text, you can use base64_encode() and base64_decode(). But this won't stop any experienced user to read the actual value.

Use mcrypt() to crypt the message, base64_encode() to make the crypted version ASCII, include it in the URL, and on the next page decode and then decrypt. Be carefull, a lot of chippers use seed value, which also have to be saved and send to the next page, in order to be able to decrypt.

All scenarios assume the next page is part of the same application (or both applications are yours). If you want to encrypt the string for any URL, you can't, as the page you are redirecting to won't be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these PHP functions [convert_uuencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) and [convert_uudecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uudecode.php)

It is much safer than using only base64

```
function encrypt_decrypt ($data, $encrypt) {
    if ($encrypt == true) {
        $output = base64_encode (convert_uuencode ($data));
    } else {
        $output = convert_uudecode (base64_decode ($data));
    }
    return $output;
}

$enc_txt = encrypt_decrypt ("TEXT PLAIN", true);
echo $enc_txt."\n";
// KjUkNTg1IiEwMyQlKTNAYGAKYAo=
echo encrypt_decrypt ($enc_txt, false);
// TEXT PLAIN
```